# Different predictor variable, same result

Tags: r, prediction

I am following the predictive modeling example found [here](https://mdsr-book.github.io/mdsr2e/ch-modeling.html#predictive-modeling), chapter 10.

In the code below, I see `capital_gain` as the predictor variable for `income`. If I replace `income` with another (numeric) variable of the `census` data, e.g. `hours_per_week` nothing will change in the outcome. The model accuracy seems to be the same and the confusion matrix is the same. What goes wrong in my thinking and/or doing?

```
library(yardstick)
pred <- train %>%
  select(income, capital_gain) %>%
  bind_cols(
    predict(mod_null, new_data = train, type = "class")
  ) %>%
  rename(income_null = .pred_class)
accuracy(pred, income, income_null)
```

Comment: That code is using a previously defined `mod_null` model. The predictor and response are defined in the `mod_null` definition which you don't show. The code in your question is pulling a couple columns out along with model predictions - you can pull whatever columns you want, but the model isn't changing unless you update the `mod_null <- ...` definition.